# How to create a custom voronoi diagram with cycles nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, procedural

I've been looking for a way to create my own Voronoi diagram using cycles nodes, I've seen scripts that do just that but I wanted to create it using just math nodes within the Shader Editor, besides I know nothing about scripting shaders or textures. Anyway, the reason behind this is that I want to have control over the points location, this to recreate the patterns seen on reptile skins, like the example below.
[image: Example of reptile skin]

Having control over the points location could allow me to vary the scale, flow and evenness of the scales which is just what I'm looking for.

Also, if someone could show me the way to assign texture coordinates to each cell, so I can put unique textures for each cell, I would highly appreciate it!
[image]

I'm open for workarounds but I really want it to be for procedural texturing without doing many manual actions. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that can realistically be achieved with procedural approaches. Also giving texture coordinates to each cell won't necessarily enable you to assign unique textures for each.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I already solved the texture coordinate point, and it works, it's not as fancy as it sounded. The main problem is still unsolved. I really thought it was possible, since everything at heart is math calculations. Thanks anyway, I'll wait hoping someone can point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about unique textures. You can use image with different textures and then make unique uv-shift for each cell by random or bu positions

Zero position for each:
[image: uv starts at center of each Voronoy cell]

Then add rule for position-shift.
in this case it is stepped random add (color):
[image: random uv shift by cell]

So if your texture contains tiles, that bigger than cells you can fill it.

Also you can choose texture by mix like if cell size is bigger than X, put another texture (or shift UV)[image: change textures per voronoy cells]